# CSS selector for Safari 5 only

Tags: css, safari, cross-browser

I am developing a web page and when I test for cross-browsing testing I got my CSS style got conflict with my google chrome and my safari 5.

my code for all browsers ( firefox, chrome, opera)

```
.flex-direction-nav-featured a{
       margin-top: 4%;
   }
```

I try this one but it wont work

```
/* for safari only (wont work)*/
::root .flex-direction-nav-featured a{
    margin-top: 5%;
}
/* for safari only (but works with chrome also)*/
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
      /* works with sfari and chrome */
   .flex-direction-nav-featured a{
       margin-top: 5%;
   } 

}
```

Is there a CSS hack which only targets Safari 5? I have tried many things but none worked.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What works in Chrome? What doesn't work in Safari?

Comment: Is this Safari on PC?

Comment: yes, it is on safari on PC and laptop

Comment: The proper solution probably isn't to resort to CSS hack. There is likely something else that is being overlooked in the code. ie. Missing float, improper display, etc. Can you provide more source or a working example?

Comment: A JS Fiddle could be usefull here! But of course also post the code in the Q since that is what the FAQs state.

Answer (score 13):

You might want to try to block chrome via a pseudoclass:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    .flex-direction-nav-featured a{
        margin-top: 4%;
    } 

    /* Safari only override */
    ::i-block-chrome,.flex-direction-nav-featured a{
        margin-top: 5%;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 
    /* Safari only override */
    ::i-block-chrome,.flex-direction-nav-featured a {
        margin-top: 5%;
    } 
}
```